# Force refresh and clear cache - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, caching

I am facing an issue here . And i don't know if there is something possible to do about it .
When my application receives a new version from the Back End and if you are already logged in the user gets an HTTP error 500 . 
So in order to fix it he will need to refresh the browser and clear the cache .
So i ask myself is there a way conditionally to check the version and if the version is the old one clear the cache and refresh the browser .

I have already gave a try of this code . Basically not to store any cache from this app , but it seems that this is not the solution that i am looking for .

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a pattern like that:

```
script.js?v=1
```

It will be the same as `script.js` but the browser treats it differently because simply it has a kind of different version and retrieves it from the `server`, not from the `cache`

Comment: can you give some example . I am a little bit confused about that . Thank you